# Azure service bus subscriber model

Tags: azure

What is the expected/ recommended strategy (or maybe practice is the better word here) for building/ running/ deploying subscribers to Azure Service Bus in Azure?

I would have assumed there was some infrastructure to support that, but as far as I can figure out the expectation is to build Windows services and host them on VMs in the Azure environment and deploy them through some kind of custom mechanism.  Is that accurate?  I'd prefer not to do that if there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure service bus is not platform dependent.  Subscriptions to a topic can be retrieved on many platforms and languages.  In node.js (available on various platforms) you would import the azure package ( `npm install azure`)   Subsequently your node.js code would be like (with the default MatchAll filter:

```
serviceBusService.createSubscription('MyTopic','ShowAllMessages',function(error){
    if(!error){
        // subscription created
    }
});
```

As far as best practice goes it depends on what types of service bus constructs you are deploying.  Android devices might be better off using Azure mobile apps (which would create an Azure based PAAS backend).  Full thick clients might run python scripts. There isn't 1 suggested pattern due to the breadth of options available.

Comment: I was hoping for an "easy" solution, but oh well.  Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Without more context I can't make it easier.